# Synaptic package manager has stopped working in Ubuntu 12.04 Unity

Tags: 12.04, unity, kde, synaptic

Synaptic package manager was working in my Ubuntu 12.04 installation under Unity, but it recently stopped working for no apparent reason. It does work when I switch to KDE. Suggestions?

Comment: by KDE do you mean kubuntu-desktop or kubuntu?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Do you get any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem some time ago. I solved typing in a terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface toolkit-accessibility false
```

But you sould provide further details to understand if you have the same problem I had.
If the above solution won't work, please edit your answer with verbose information, such as the output of running synaptic by terminal.